# How to correct type inference for a parameter of a curried function's function parameter that is inferred as unknown?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, type-inference, currying

When using a curried functions that separately accept a function & list, how can the function parameter's parameter be correctly inferred (avoiding inferring as `unknown`) from the list if the order of currying is accept a function as the first parameter THEN accept a list as the second parameter? - Is this possible? If not, what is the best approach here to provide a good function API to improve the developer experience?

For example, in the below snippet, a `selector` function is passed as the first parameter to the first curried function, and it's parameter `i` should provide the type `T` that provides type inference for the second parameter `numbers` of the second curried function.

However, `select`'s `i` parameter is inferred as type `unknown` - why is this the case?

How can the example be changed so that `i`'s & `list`'s inferred types are both `Item`?

```
const select = <T>(selector: (i: T) => T) => (numbers: T[]) => numbers.map(selector);
interface Item { name: string; }
const items: Item[] = [{ name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name2' }];

// ERROR: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown' (`i` is type `unknown`, `items` is type `Item[]`).
select(i => i.name)(items);
```

Comment: You cannot infer the type for the first call using the second call. Imagine it was written like `const temp = select(i => i.name); temp(items)`. Here on the first call TS has no way to know what is the type of `i`. You must either specify the generic by hand (`select<Item>(i => t.name)(items)`), type the argument (`select((i: Item) => i.name)(items)`) or swap the functions (`select(items)(i => i.name)`)

Comment: @AlexChashin That makes sense, I was assuming arrow functions could provide a form of chained inference but I realize now that they're separate expressions - your comment could be posted as answer & accepted to help others. Regarding your other points, I've used the `select<Item>` & `select((i: Item)...)` approaches before but wasn't sure if that's a good API for the function user. I was considering swapping the order of the functions but that removes conveniences like `const getName = select(i => i.name);`. If possible, can you advise on the preferred approach in TS or functional-programming?

Comment: Well, whatever works better for you :p I prefer `select<Item>` syntax but it really doesn't matter. You can look at existing selector libraries like [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) and see what API they use (looking at their code seems like they prefer the `(i: Item)` syntax) but it really doesn't matter

Comment: Good points, I asked in case there was a convention & I appreciate the detailed answer. Finally is there a preference in the ordering of curried functions? For example, the `select` example I showed seems to have the first parameter `selector` as a sort of config/action on then next data parameter  `list` - it seems aimed at performing a reusable action on many data lists - I'm not sure if this is a common convention or a good way to set up curried functions but would like to learn more (haven't found much on this ordering yet).

Comment: Please focus less of conventions, following best practices is a good idea, but you shouldn't think in terms of them all the time :P. I'd say that for a selector function it indeed makes much more sense to accept the selector function first, and then the actual object. It's how selector libraries usually do it, and using different selector functions for the same object is probably a much rarer scenario then multiple objects with the same selector. But anyway, do whatever works for you best and whatever you consider more convenient

Comment: @AlexChashin _You cannot infer the type for the first call using the second call._ Why not? TS could infer the most general type of `i`, which is `{name: T}`. In the second call TS must ensure that `Item` is a subtype of `{name: T}`, which holds from a structural perspective. Since TS pursues structural typing it should hold too.

Comment: You probably meant `{name: unknown}`. Maybe this would be a nice feature, but TS currently doesn't support it. If it can't infer the type of the argument at the point of the definition of the function, and you don't provide your own type, it assumes it is `any` and shows an error. Maybe this would be a nice feature, although this statement is arguable. Imagine you did `i => i.age.toFixed()`, what type is it supposed to infer? You probably meant `i` to be `{age: number}`, but maybe it should `{age: {toFixed: () => unknown}}`? And this `unknown` in the return type will be hard to work with